# Adding list of items with one type to another object

Tags: c#

This seems like a fairly straight forward issue, but for some reason I'm having a hard time with it. I have a class, QualificationDto:

```
public class QualificationDto
{
    public QualificationDto()
    {

    }
    [DataMember]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Int32 QualificationId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]

    public List<CredentialDto> Credentials { get; set; }

}
```

It contains a list of CrentialDto:

```
public class CredentialDto
{
    public CredentialDto()
    {

    }

    public CredentialDto(int id, string name)
    {
        CredentialId = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public Int32 CredentialId { get; set; }

}
```

CredentialDto has other properties, but all I'm really concerned about is  "CredentialId".

What I would like to do is "transfer" the "CredentialId"s into an IList in another class, QualificationEntity:

```
public class QualificationEntity
{   
    public virtual String Name{ get; set; }
    public virtual Int32 QualificationId{ get; set; }
    public virtual IList<CredentialEntity> CredentialsList { get ;set ;}
}
```

CredentialEntity:

```
public class CredentialEntity 
{
    public CredentialEntity()
    {

    }

    public virtual Int32 CredentialId { get; set; }
}
```

The whole point of all of this is that I need to populate the "CredentialsList" (In QualificationEntity) with the IDs from "Credentials" (In QualificationDto at the top).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that `qualificationDto` is an instance of an object of type `QualificationDto`, you could get what you want, with a simple projection of each item in the `Credentials` list, like below:

```
var credentialsList = qualificationDto.Credentials
                                      .Select(c => new 
                                              CredentialEntity(c.CredentialId)
                                     ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for. It will create a new `CredentialEntity` for each `CredentialDto` into a new list and copy each id.

```
qualificationEntry.CredentialsList = qualificationDto.Credentials.Select(c =>
    new CredentialEntity
    {
        CredentialId = c.CredentialId
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (CredentialDto credential in QualificationDto.Credentials)
{
   CredentialEntity entity = new CredentialEntity();
   entity.CredentialId=CredentialDto.CredentialId;
   QualificationEntity.CredentialsList.Add(entity)
}
```

This is what you wanted. Correct me if I didn't understand you correctly.